# Verifying $\gamma$ is a representation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of the following theorem due to Frobenius appearing in the book Topics in Combinatorial Group Theory by Baumslag.

**Definition** Let $G$ be a group, $H \leq G$. Then a complete set of representatives of the right cosets $Hg$ of $H$ in $G$ is a set $R$ consisting of exactly one element from each coset. The elements in $R$ coming from the coset $Hg$ is denoted by $\overline{g}$. element $\overline{g}$ is termed as the representative of $g$. If $1\in R$, $R$ is termed a right transversal in $G$.

$\textbf{Theorem}$:Let $G$ be a group, $H\leq R$ and let $R$ be a right transversal of $H$. Then the homomorphism 
$\gamma: G \rightarrow Perm(R)$ defined by:
$g\mapsto(\gamma_g : \overline{r} \mapsto \overline{rg})$

is a representation of $G$, sometimes termed as a coset representation of $G$.

I understand the fact that for every $g\in G$, $\gamma_g :R \rightarrow R$ is a bijection and therefore $\gamma_g\in Perm(R)$, but I am having hard time understanding why $\gamma: G \rightarrow Perm(R)$ is a homomorphism.

What I was hoping to see was $\gamma_g\circ\gamma_h=\gamma_{gh}$. But this is what happens : $\gamma_g\circ\gamma_h(\overline{r})=\gamma_g(\overline{ rh})=\overline{\overline{rh}g}=\overline{rhg}=\gamma_{hg}(r)$

Would someone help me to understand this better?

Comment: I think this is just a matter of left or right actions. The way you have defined it, $\gamma_g$ is acting on $R$ on the right, whereas if you write $\gamma_h(r)$ then you are trying to act on the left. So to get $\gamma_g \circ \gamma_h = \gamma_{gh}$ you have to think of the composition $\gamma_g \circ \gamma_h$ as meaning first apply $\gamma_g$ then apply $\gamma_h$.

Comment: how do you define $Perm(R)$ ?

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks. I see now, this does makes sense now.

Comment: @KonKan I was think of it as $\{f:R\rightarrow R \mid \mbox{f is a bijection} \}$. Is this definition correct?

Comment: I am not sure. But what I know is that if you want to speak about a group  homomorphism you have to be clear about what is the target set and which is the "operation" which makes it into a group. Is it composition of functions (as implied in your post) or is it multiplication inside $R$ ?

Comment: So I was I thinking of it as Perm(R) is a group with composition as its group product. You are right, I should have been more clear about this.

Comment: It would be helpful to cite the text you are studying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would pose it as follows: Since
$$
g\mapsto(\gamma_g : \overline{r} \mapsto \overline{rg})
$$
then
$$
gh\mapsto\Big(\gamma_{gh} : \overline{r} \mapsto \overline{r(gh)}=
\overline{(rh)g}=\overline{\overline{rh}g}=
\gamma_g\big(\overline{rh}\big)=
\gamma_g\big(\gamma_h(\overline{r})\big)=
\gamma_g\circ\gamma_h
\Big)
$$
thus:
$$
\gamma_{gh}=\gamma_{g}\circ\gamma_{h}
$$
The reason is that, generally for right actions, we have (so that the action definition is satisfied):
$$
g\cdot(ab)=(g\cdot b)\cdot a
$$